mprotect errors at qemu-system-x86_64 startup
I just updated my Alpine Linux to version 3.20, and I encountered this error:
phy0:~# qemu-system-x86_64
qemu-system-x86_64: qemu_mprotect__osdep: mprotect failed: Permission denied
qemu-system-x86_64: mprotect of jit buffer: Permission denied

I've tried:

restarting my server
changing permissions on /dev/kvm
removing my configuration and using the default one
modprobe several modules, including kvm, virtio, and tun
re-installing all the packages with apk info | xargs apk fix

Libvirt now cannot see Qemu installed on the system; 'no hypervisor options were found for this connection'.
Before that, I had a libvirt environment that worked great for a decade.
The current Qemu version is:
phy0:~# qemu-system-x86_64 -version
QEMU emulator version 9.0.2

I don't even know where to start searching for a solution. Thanks for your help.
EDIT: FYI, I tried to run qemu in a chroot (with an Alpine environment), same thing. It doesn't appear to be a problem with the distribution, though, since I can run qemu on an Alpine system inside a freshly created test VM.

I fixed the problem by changing the kernel.
As I said, I installed my server a decade ago, when grsec patches were a thing in the default installation of an Alpine distribution. It worked great… until now.
The solution:
apk del linux-hardened
apk add linux-lts
reboot

Goodbye grsec patches…
I still have no idea why it stopped working all of a sudden. But since the last kernel with those patches was really old, I'm not sure I wanted to keep it anyway.
